# Silverlight 4: DataForm, currentItem and AutoCommit

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dataform

I have a DataGrid and a DataForm. I'm assigning data to the DataForm with the currently selected Item in the datagrid individually as `DataForm.CurrentItem`. This means that I do not have any Next/Previous button on the DataForm and the user can switch to any row in the DataGrid.

My problem is that although I have set the property `AutoCommit="True"` on the DataForm, if the user edits something and clicks on another record in the DataGrid, it crashes.

How can I force it to save the DataForm when the user moves away from the form?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working but I'm not sure whether this is correct. On SelectionChanged event of datagrid I added the following:

```
DataForm.CommitEdit();
```

and it stopped crashing and giving me the error. If anyone else has a better solution please do let me know.