# Silverlight dataform currentitem issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, currency, dataform

I have a page with two controls on it, a datagrid and a dataform.

In the datagrid, I have a list of all the objects of a certain class. When a user selects an item in the datagrid, the dataform is loaded with the selected object.

dataForm.CurrentItem = view.CurrentItem;
view is a PagedCollectionView which contains only the selected item.

My problem is, when setting the dataform's currenitem property, if I use just the PagedCollectionView (view) without .CurrentItem, I lose the validation on the dataform. All the required fields are not seen as required. If I use the pcv.CurrentItem as my dataform's CurrentItem validation works fine, but then another issue arrises.

When I use the PagedCollectionView's current item as the dataform's current item:

A user selects an item in the datagrid and the object is loaded fine in the dataform. If a user changes a certain value in any of the textfields on the dataform and then selects a different item to load the dataform with, the following error is thrown:

"Cannot change currency when an item has validation errors or it is being edited and AutoCommit is false.  Set ItemsSource to a ICollectionView to manage currency instead."
I am not using the paging properties of the dataform and I have my own save button on the form.

I would appreciate any help, this is my first silverlight project that I am working on.

Edit- I used dataform.CommitEdit when changing the dataform's currentitem. One thing that this did not resolve is if there is a validation error on the form, the currency error is thrown. Is there anyway to bypass this. AutoEdit is true and AutoCommit is false for the dataform

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit hard to determine exactly what's going on here without a sample, but here's an observation that may help resolve the problem.  Try instead to bind the ItemsSource property of both the DataGrid and the DataForm to the collection view, and *don't* bind the DataForm's CurrentItem property.  They're magically kept in sync (the selected item in the DataGrid will set the current item in the DataForm) - this is a feature of the CollectionView.  This may or may not solve your problem, but either way it won't hurt :).

Blatant self promotion: this and other features of the CollectionView are covered in my book [Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272074) :).

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this method and I still get the same error.

Comment: I tried what Jhelumi did in his post (seems we had the same problem) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969588/silverlight-4-and-dataform-and-currenitem-and-autocommit

Comment: And this seems to have solved the issue. Thank you very much though

Comment: This also worked for me. In one of my scenarios where I wasn't using a PagedCollectionView, I added a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=VS.95).aspx) and bound both the DataGrid and DataForm ItemsSource to this to get the SelectedItem / CurrentItem sync behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a lot of times. And always in case add new item.
After few frustrating days I downloaded source codes of [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).
(You could find in Programs FIles directory (Mine were is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Source) )
Compile and reference instead of assembly **System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit**

In Debug mode we see strange behavior in DataForm.cs:

```
private static void OnCurrentItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataForm dataForm = d as DataForm;
            if (dataForm != null && !dataForm.AreHandlersSuspended())
            {
                if (dataForm._lastItem != null && dataForm.ShouldValidateOnCurrencyChange)
                {
                    dataForm.ValidateItem();
                }

                if ((!dataForm.AutoCommitPreventsCurrentItemChange && dataForm.IsItemValid) &&
                    (e.NewValue == null ||
                    dataForm._collectionView == null ||
                    dataForm._collectionView.Contains(dataForm.CurrentItem) 
                    ))
                {
                    dataForm.SetUpNewCurrentItem();
                    dataForm.GenerateUI(true /* clearEntityErrors */, true /* swapOldAndNew */);
                    dataForm.UpdateCurrentItem();
                    SetAllCanPropertiesAndUpdate(dataForm, false /* onlyUpdateStates */);
                    dataForm._lastItem = dataForm.CurrentItem;
                    dataForm.OnCurrentItemChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    dataForm.SetValueNoCallback(e.Property, e.OldValue);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit.Resources.DataForm_CannotChangeCurrency, "AutoCommit", "ItemsSource", "ICollectionView"));
                }
            }
        }
```

> **dataForm._collectionView.Contains(dataForm.CurrentItem)** returns false even the same object exists in dataForm._collectionView

I changed conditional:

```
if ((!dataForm.AutoCommitPreventsCurrentItemChange && dataForm.IsItemValid) &&
                    (e.NewValue == null ||
                    dataForm._collectionView == null ||
                    dataForm._collectionView.Contains(dataForm.CurrentItem) || 
                    dataForm.CurrentItem == e.NewValue
                    ))
```

And DataForm started work fine. Without exception and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DataForm_EditEnding(object sender, DataFormEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataFormEditAction.Commit)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        DataForm1.ValidationSummary.Errors.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for any validation error when you are binding the current item, if you have any then clear them BindingItem.ValidationErrors.Clear(); then bind the item to dataform.